# Load xaml file and filter tags and values using c/c++

Tags: c++, c, xaml

Is there a way to load a .xaml file data, filter the tags, and check values?
For instance, using the bellow code, how can I get all 'variable' tags and check if is 'String'and check if the value contains come specific keyword (using c/c++)?

Thank you

```
 <Flowchart.Variables>
    <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="strDebugDt" />
    <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="strMailFilter" />
    <Variable x:TypeArguments="sd:DataTable" Name="dtReportAttachments" />
</Flowchart.Variables>
```

Comment: To answer the question asked: yes, there is a way. Using a proper parser library. Unfortunately, asking where to find it, or to recommend one, is off-topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: Do you suggest other approach/language? And if not, can you suggest a global solution using a parser library? It probably would be something like importing data and loop all tags? Thank you

Comment: As I said, these kinds of recommendations are, unfortunately, off topic. I don't make the rules here.

Comment: To answer the question, no, there is no way using **C/C++**, because C and C++ are different languages.  Pick one.  Yes, one can parse and load an .xaml file using either language.  You may want to use libraries rather than write your own parser.

Comment: See [softwarerecs.se] before posting there.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasMatthews. When I said c/c++ I meant I would like to use one of this because It's the main college programming language. I do see a lot of libraries to parse xaml for c# and some xaml readers for java, but i can't find anything relating c++. I've been looking for some time now. Any help on this?